# setting a param from the launch file doesn't work with string

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to set a param using the launch file like so:

```
<node name="right_sensor" pkg="action" type="input_signal" output="screen" >
    <param name="port" value="55551" />
    <param name="signal_name" value="right" />
</node>
```

In my code I have this:

```
  string port, signal_name;
 
  ros::NodeHandle private_node_handle_("~");
  private_node_handle_.param("signal_name", signal_name, string("signal"));
  private_node_handle_.param("port", port, string("55555"));

  ROS_INFO("PORT: %s", port.c_str());
  ROS_INFO("Signal Name: %s", signal_name.c_str());
```

It appears that the "port" is not transferred correctly (I get "55555").

Only "signal_name" is correct.

BTW, if I add a letter before the value of the param in port (e.g. "a55551), it will be ok.

Can anyone assist?
Is this a bug or a feature?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193374/setting-a-param-from-the-launch-file-doesn%27t-work-with-string/) by [MosheS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20148/moshes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-24**:
Did you try setting the type in the launch file with `type="string"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

55551 will be resolved to `integer` and port is expecting `string`, so port is getting default value. Specifying the type attribute will solve it.

From [wiki roslaunch XML param](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param)

> If you don't specify the type,
> roslaunch will attempt to
> automatically determine the type.
> These rules are very basic:

> numbers with '.'s are floating point, integers otherwise;

> "true" and "false" are boolean (not case-sensitive).

> all other values are strings

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-09-24**:
Just to complement, adding `type="string"` to the launch file solves the problem when you set the parameter in that file. However, if you don't, the default value will be used. Hence, you could also explicitly call `private_node_handle_.param<string>(...)` to guarantee type safety at compile time.